# ZSH set socks5 proxy by tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy

I can set Chrome proxy by Tor. Can use Tor socks5 to set shell proxy?
I tried but failed.
I think no way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have zsh installed to try it, but you could try using it with torsocks. For example with bash, you can run `torsocks bash`. This will launch a bash shell that will redirect new TCP network connections through Tor. It would probably work for zsh as well with `torsocks zsh`.

It's important to note that not all network traffic will be redirected through Tor when using torsocks (torsocks is not a sandbox and there is no fail-safe). Non-TCP network traffic will be sent without Tor, and any applications that access the network without using libc will also be sent without Tor.

Comment: 通过对torsoks的研究，我了解到了proxychains-ng. 现在，我通过proxychains4加tor browser的socks5实现了代理zsh。git也可以通过tor browser的socks5 127.0.0.1实现代理。    By researching torsoks, I learned about proxychains-ng. Now, I implement proxy zsh through proxychains4 and tor browser's socks5. git can also implement proxy through tor browser's socks5 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Great Firewall can no longer stop me, I am free, thank God!